# Trouble migrating an offline Wordpress site to another PC

Tags: wordpress, xampp

So I was working on my website on my home PC and needed to finish up on it on my work PC in the office. I managed to copy the wordpress folder in htdocs(working with XAMPP) plus the exported database file onto the work PC and configured everything correctly but the site doesn't seem to read the database files. I try to run the url: localhost:8080/tech/ and it takes me to the installation of wordpress.

Note: port 80 on work pc is in use had to change XAMPP port to 8080.

I can't access the pages I had created for some reason.

Comment: Your wp_config.php is correctly configured with the new parameters ? Have a check in your database too, in the wp_options table. You have to make some change (like site_url and base_url).

Comment: @Paul Yes everything is configured properly in the wp-config.php, but I can't find the wp-options table you're talking of

Comment: Check this : https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/site-url-and-home-url-wordpress/

Comment: Have you imported the database correctly on the new pc location? It shouldn't be asking you to do a new installation. You can check the `wp_options` in phpmyadmin on the site and home urls, to make sure it matches the new pc localhost.